# How to delete all voice memos stored on iphone in one go?

Tags: iphone, ios, voice-memo

The Voice Memo app makes deleting several/all memos rather cumbersome as there doesn't seem to be an option to select all at once. SO how to delete all voice memos stored on my iPhone in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use iCloud to sync your voice memos you can delete the Voice Memo app (same as any other app deletion) and redownload it from the App Store. This will delete any Voice Memos stored only on the phone.